# Cuda debugging using Single GPU with visual studio

Tags: debugging, cuda, nsight

I am working on Windows 7, Visual studio 2010.

Can we debug cuda code using single GPU which also providing display to the monitor in the same PC?
What tools are available ? NSIGHT seems to be working with  two GPUs.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 support has been dropped in newer versions of Nsight, (see [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-requirements)) basically anything that was released in 2020 or newer.  So you're stuck with older versions.  Older versions will also have a support chart like the one I previously linked which explains the supported debug scenarios.  Generally speaking, single GPU debug as you describe should be possible with a "newer" GPU like Kepler or newer.

The last Nsight version that supported Win 7 is 2019.4 and the associated [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/2019.4/Nsight_Visual_Studio_Edition_User_Guide.htm#System_Requirements.htm) indicates support for single GPU debugging.

Note that in the 2019.x timeframe, the Nsight tools had both a "legacy" and "next gen" debugger, and the one you should use will depend on which GPU you are using (and possibly driver model WDDM/TCC), see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/2019.4/Nsight_Visual_Studio_Edition_User_Guide.htm#System_Requirements.htm#Compute_Debugger_Support).

Also note that the last CUDA toolkit that had official support for VS 2010 was in the [CUDA 9.x generation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/9.0/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).